# React Router go back to current page after redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-v4

I have a problem with redirection after login. It works when I hardcode the result but when I call the api to check authentication it will redirect to "/main" and go back to the current page "LoginForm".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginForm from './components/login/LoginFormContainer';
import Main from './components/main/MainContainer';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact name="login" path="/" component={LoginForm} />
          <Route exact name="main" path="/main" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in my loginPage redirect to "/main" after check authentication

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FieldGroup from '../common/FormGroup';
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../../img/zonLogo.svg';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handleLoginClick(e) {
    var form = new FormData()
    form.append("username", "xxxxx");
    form.append("password", "xxxxx");
    let self = this;

    fetch('/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: form
    }).then(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.json()
    }
    }).then(function (data) {
  i    f (data.user !== undefined && !data.user.isSuspended &&     !data.user.banned) {
        self.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Call report API error");
    });
  }

render() {

if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
  return <Redirect to="main" />;
}
return (
  <div >
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleLoginClick}>
          <FieldGroup
            id="username"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"/>
          <FieldGroup
            id="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            />
          <Button type="submit" block> Log in</Button>
        </Form>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div >
);
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

when login successfully it will redirect to main but it redirect back to login page but if I hardcode it will work

```
handleLoginClick(e) {
    self.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
}
```

Comment: One potential clue: when your form is submitted, your handleLoginClick method is called but also, your page is refreshed. So even though it redirects via react, it reloads the page hence the issue. Try adding e.preventDefault() as the first line in handleLoginClick and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Hossein Thanks It works